# R: Manipulate and ggplot2 moving density curve not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

Thought I would ask the question with a well setup pair of examples:

- The first example (first chunk of code) has a normal distribution of products, and a moving limit determines what passes and fails, producing a yield (this one works, and it does by moving the geom_vline, or the red vertical line).
- The second example (second chunk of code) has a normal distribution of varying mean, and the limit is stationary at 0 (I tried moving the geom_density using manipulate and couldn't get it to work)

**Question:** How do I get manipulate to work with ggplot2 to move a density curve (and get my second example to work)?

First Example:

```
require(manipulate)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(10)
data <- data.frame(dens=rnorm(1000, mean=20, sd=3))

# Moving the limit, Production always the same
manipulate(
{
    Pass <- sum(data>Limit)
    Fail <- sum(data<=Limit)
    Yield <- Pass/(Pass+Fail)*100
    labPass <- paste0("Pass=",toString(Pass))
    labFail <- paste0("Fail=",toString(Fail))
    labYield <- paste0("Yield=",formatC(Yield,format="f", digits=2),"%")

    ggplot(data) +
        geom_density(aes(x=dens), fill="white") +
        labs(title="Product Yield") +
        xlim(-5,30) +
        xlab("Normal Dist. mean=20, sd=3") +
        ylab("Density") +
        geom_vline(xintercept=Limit, linetype="longdash", colour="red") +
        annotate("text", x=Limit-3, y=0.10, label=labPass)+
        annotate("text", x=Limit-3, y=0.09, label=labFail)+
        annotate("text", x=Limit-3, y=0.08, label=labYield)
},
Limit=slider(5,20, initial=5))
```

Second Example (move geom_density <- not working):

```
require(manipulate)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(10)
data <- data.frame(dens=rnorm(1000, mean=20, sd=3))

# Limit the same, Production mean moves
manipulate(
{
    Pass <- sum(data-20+MoveM>0)
    Fail <- sum(data-20+MoveM<=0)
    Yield <- Pass/(Pass+Fail)*100
    labPass <- paste0("Pass=",toString(Pass))
    labFail <- paste0("Fail=",toString(Fail))
    labYield <- paste0("Yield=",formatC(Yield,format="f", digits=2),"%")

    ggplot(data) +
        geom_density(aes(x=dens-20+MoveM), fill="white") +
        labs(title="Product Yield") +
        xlim(-5,30) +
        xlab("Normal Dist. mean=variable, sd=3") +
        ylab("Density") +
        geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="longdash", colour="red") +
        annotate("text", x=-3, y=0.10, label=labPass)+
        annotate("text", x=-3, y=0.09, label=labFail)+
        annotate("text", x=-3, y=0.08, label=labYield)
},
MoveM=slider(0,20, initial=20))
```

Image for the first example:
[image]

Comment: I tried to add the "manipulate" tag for the manipulate package, but could not.

Comment: I'd suggest to change `dens` beforehand like `ggplot(transform(data, dens = dens-20+MoveM)) + geom_density(aes(x=dens))` or to add `MoveM` as another `data` column. Interesting package btw.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, adding the extra column to the dataframe worked marvelously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a solution from lukeA's comment, here is the code that moves the density curve with the mean.

### Yield curve in R by moving the mean of the distribution, and having a stationary acceptance limit:

```
require(manipulate)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(10)
data <- data.frame(dens=rnorm(1000, mean=20, sd=3))

# Limit the same, Production mean moves
manipulate(
{
    Pass <- sum(data$dens-20+MoveM>0)
    Fail <- sum(data$dens-20+MoveM<=0)
    Yield <- Pass/(Pass+Fail)*100
    labPass <- paste0("Pass=",toString(Pass))
    labFail <- paste0("Fail=",toString(Fail))
    labYield <- paste0("Yield=",formatC(Yield,format="f", digits=2),"%")
    # ANSWER to Question: Use extra column in dataframe
    data$shiftDens <- data$dens - 20 + MoveM

    ggplot(data) +
        geom_density(aes(x=shiftDens), fill="white") +
        labs(title="Product Yield") +
        xlim(-5,30) +
        xlab("Normal Dist. mean=variable, sd=3") +
        ylab("Density") +
        geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="longdash", colour="red") +
        annotate("text", x=-3, y=0.10, label=labPass)+
        annotate("text", x=-3, y=0.09, label=labFail)+
        annotate("text", x=-3, y=0.08, label=labYield)
},
MoveM=slider(0,20, initial=20))
```

[image]